# Dynamic Allocation not creating array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

I'm doing an assignment for school and we're doing memory management. So far we're tasked to basically just create a list of students + id's and we're to do it dynamically.

I'm also supposed to overload the delete/new operators, which I've already done. However when testing out my program it would crash, possibly not creating the array to allocate the information.

```
namespace
{
char buffer[1024];
int allocated = 0;
}
struct student
{
int size;
char *firstname;
char lastname;
int studentId;
int occupied;

student::student() : size(0)
{
}

student::student(int s) : size(s)
{
    std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Allocated: " << allocated << std::endl;
    int currentLoc = allocated;
    allocated += s;
    firstname = new (&buffer[currentLoc]) char[s];
}

void *student::operator new(size_t s)
{
    std::cout << "Operator new allocated: " << allocated << std::endl;
int currentLoc = allocated;
allocated += s;
return &buffer[currentLoc];
}

    void student::operator delete(void *ptr)
{
    std::cout << "Delete called " << std::endl;
    std::free(ptr);
}

student::~student()
{
}
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
student *studentlist = new student[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Fill in the first name for the student." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> studentlist[i].firstname;
    std::cout << "Fill in the last name for the student." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> studentlist[i].lastname;
    studentlist[i].studentId = (rand() % (9999 - 999)) + 999;
    studentlist[i].occupied = 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Edited to current version

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I assume you've either solved it, or you spent enough time on it by now and moved on to something else. Either way, I was going to update my answer to reflect the new details you gave me and provide a simple memory pool example.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Student
{
   Student( )
   : firstname( NULL ), lastname( NULL ), id( 0 ), occupied( false )
   { }
   Student( const char* fn, const char* ln, int id_ )
   : firstname( fn ), lastname( ln ), id( id_ )
   {
   }

   static void* operator new(size_t s);
   static void operator delete( void *ptr );

   const char* firstname;
   const char* lastname;
   int id;
   bool occupied;
};

static const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
Student buffer[ BUFSIZE ];

void* Student::operator new(size_t s)
{
   void* ret;
   for ( int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; ++i )
   {
      if ( !buffer[ i ].occupied )
      {
         buffer[ i ].occupied = true;
         ret = &buffer[ i ];
         break;
      }
   }
   return ret;
}

void Student::operator delete( void *ptr )
{
   reinterpret_cast<Student*>( ptr )->occupied = false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   static const int NUM_STUDENTS = 3;
   Student* students[ NUM_STUDENTS ];

   // Create the students
   students[ 0 ] = new Student( "Jack",    "Daniels",  42 );
   students[ 1 ] = new Student( "Johnny",  "Walker",   283 );
   students[ 2 ] = new Student( "Jim",     "Bean",     111 );

   std::cout << "Address of memory pool: " << &buffer[ 0 ] << std::endl;

   for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i )
   {
      Student* s = students[ i ];
      bool* occupied = &( s->occupied );
      int slot = std::distance( buffer, s );

      std::cout << "Student addr: " << s << std::endl;

      // Slot should be occupied
      std::cout << "Slot " << slot << " is being occupied: " << std::boolalpha
         << *occupied << std::endl;

      // Print student
      std::cout << "Occupying Student (" << s->id << ") = " << std::string( s->firstname )
         << " " << std::string( s->lastname ) << "" << std::endl;

      std::cout << "Student is about to be deleted" << std::endl;

      // Exercise your delete operator
      delete s;

      // Slot should be vacant
      std::cout << "Slot " << slot << " is being occupied: " << std::boolalpha
         << *occupied << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Running that produces:

```
Address of memory pool: 0x100407000
Student addr: 0x100407000
Slot 0 is being occupied: true
Occupying Student (42) = Jack Daniels
Student is about to be deleted
Slot 0 is being occupied: false
Student addr: 0x100407018
Slot 1 is being occupied: true
Occupying Student (283) = Johnny Walker
Student is about to be deleted
Slot 1 is being occupied: false
Student addr: 0x100407030
Slot 2 is being occupied: true
Occupying Student (111) = Jim Bean
Student is about to be deleted
Slot 2 is being occupied: false
```

Comment: I've figured out what I was doing wrong. I was setting it to try to do a two dim array when I didn't need it. Setting it as a one dim array with multiple variables (Ie, First, Last, Id, etc) would be fine.

I've edited it to: 

"std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Allocated: " << allocated << std::endl;
 int currentLoc = allocated;
 allocated += s;
 firstname = new (&buffer[currentLoc]) std::string[s];"

And changed the first name back into a single pointer rather than a double.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use placement new? There's a bunch of tricky business associated with that. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Comment: std::string firstname, would default construct just fine, and you can remove all the special allocation code for it in your constructor. Or must you overload new for student and also do fancy memory allocation for one of its members?

Comment: Because this is for an assignment I'm following these restrictions:

It is Compulsory that you overwrite operator New and Operator Delete.  You should have a global array of the following Student Object of fixed size of say 1024 and use that as your backstore for allocating and freeing memory slots. Each Student Object has a flag named Occupied. You must use this to indicate if the slot is currently in use or it is free.
1) Create a Student struct as follows:
struct Student{
char *firstname;
char last name;
int studentId; 
int occupied;
}

Comment: Ah, so that's asking you to have your buffer be Student buffer[ 1024 ]; And then new needs to run through that and mark occupied = true and return the memory for that slot. The concept is called a memory pool, i.e. you have a pool of 'empty' student objects. The new overload hands them out to new student instances as they come along. I don't think you're meeting your requirements at the moment.

Comment: Also, you disobeyed the specified struct definition. Added some fancy c++ objects.  :)

Comment: Yeah I've moved it back to the specified definition. I've got it to the point where I can now ask the user to input the student names, however it'll crash after implementing the first name.

I've heard of an object pool, though this is the first I've started using it this extensively. I'll keep posting updates.

Comment: Edited OP for the new changes.

Comment: I've fixed it and moved onto the second part of the assignment, in which we're to get it to read from a text file, save the content into the variables and stress test it.

Needless to say I've been stuck on that because of the method that is required for the assignment (using char*, overloading new/delete when it seemed wholly unnecessary, etc).